# Simple JQuery Lazyload example

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I am trying to get a basic example of lazyload running, so an image only loads on click of a button.

https://jsfiddle.net/5rbhsmmc/3/

html

```
This text and 
<button class="frequently_asked">this button</button><br><br>
Image to be displayed only when the button is clicked.
<img class="lazyload" src="[image source]"/>
```

javascript

```
$('.frequently_asked').click(function() {
$('.lazyload').lazy({
bind: "event",
delay: 0
});
})
```

Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: If you want image to load only when you click button then you should add image to img after clicking button

Comment: $('.frequently_asked').click(function() {
  $('.lazyload').attr('src', $('.lazyload').data('src'));
});

Comment: That's what i was telling check above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the src as a data attribute and then copy that over to the image source when the button is pressed.

```js
$('.frequently_asked').click(function() {
    lazyLoadImages( $('.lazyload') );
});

var setImageSrcFromDataAttribute = function( imageElement ) {
    let imageUrl = imageElement.data( 'src' );
    imageElement.attr('src', imageUrl);
}

var lazyLoadImages = function( imageElements ) {
    imageElements.each( function() {
        setImageSrcFromDataAttribute( $( this ) );
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This text and
<button class="frequently_asked">this button</button><br><br> Images to be displayed only when the button is clicked.
<img class="lazyload" data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
<img class="lazyload" data-src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x200" />
<img class="lazyload" data-src="https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vTb39GuFAvCPzFXXkPfdOMbS50Si5IN2OudxLQNyTxLzuOu5uVeDnEeZXTX9ie04nsXSYBQEjckQPMg/pub?w=986&h=691" style='width:100%;max-width: 700px;' />
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I know this is a slightly different question to what I originally asked, but if I have a number of images that I want to be loaded when the user clicks the one button, is there a way to have the attr() tag include the src of the relevant image?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer to add a few more image tags and make it a little more obvious what is going on there.